# Build a Oracle ADF application jar file using Ant

Tags: oracle, ant, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am trying to write Ant scripts to build jar files for Oracle ADF application and I noticed some differences in the contents being generated by the build (deploy might be a better word actually) process within JDev and from the Ant process:

- META-INF/adfc-config.xml
- META-INF/adflibWEBINDEX.txt
- META-INF/adfm.xml
- META-INF/faces-config.xml
- META-INF/jar-adf-config.xml
- META-INF/jar-connections.xml
- META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml
- META-INF/oracle.adf.common.services.ResourceService.sva
- META-INF/task-flow-registry.xml

Does anyone know how these files are generated and how to edit the Ant scripts to include them?

I know that some of these exist in the project folder structure but when I compare their contents against the same files generated from the Jdev build produced jar file they are different. So I assume there is something more than a simple copy going on here.

Cheers,

Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use "Create buildfile from project" in JDeveloper. This will produce the calls to **ojdeploy** necessary to create/update all the extra artifacts.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/part4-098813.html